# Forward IP Addresses - NGINX and IIS

Tags: nginx, iis, ip, iis-6

We have a working NGINX redirecting our external users to our IIS server. The problem is that the IP seen by the IIS is the NGINX machine, not the IP from external users. Our logs are full of "10.0.0.2" IPs which is incorrect.

A similar configuration file is shown. We already included "proxy_set_header" lines.

Is this config file correct? What should be done at IIS server? Should we just include some topics at web.config file? If this is the case, what should we add?

```
server {
listen      10.0.0.2:443 ssl;
server_name web.mydomain.com;
ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.web.mydomain.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.web.mydomain.com.key;
error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/web.mydomain.com.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_set_header        x-real-IP       Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       https;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass      https://10.0.0.11;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/web.mydomain.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/web.mydomain.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/web.mydomain.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/web.mydomain.com/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      https://10.0.0.11;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.web.mydomain.com.conf*;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I though this would be something related to IIS/NGINX, but after @lex-li and @bruce-zhang repplies I researched more about it.

I actually did not know but inside our application (running at IIS) there are listeners to those headers, and those listeners were not properly implemented.

So it was just a misalignment between our application and NGINX.

Thanks both @lex-li and @bruce-zhang

Answer (score 0):

You can use IIS enhanced logging to write custom headers like `X-Forwarded-For` to log files,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile/customfields/add

There is no way to change the source IP field, because indeed that's IP address recorded in the TCP/HTTP packets.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe I didn't understand or my mindset is wrong. I need my ASP NET application see the IP from the user, not the NGINX IP. Until few days ago we didn't have "proxy_set_header" lines at NGINX file, so our IIS was receiving the IP 10.0.0.2 assigned to NGINX and therefore our application logs contains the same 10.0.0.2 IP. After research, the ideia is to set "X-Forwarded-For" and our application receive those IP address, but we couldn't make it work. So, is that file (shown above) correct? And what are the settings needed at IIS in order to make this work? Or maybe at web.config?

Comment: "our application receive those IP address" is true as the original IP addresses are passed via X-Forward-XX headers, but those applications must be modified to pick up the addresses from such headers if in the past they were not designed to work with reverse proxy. In short, old applications won't magically work with reverse proxy.

Comment: `proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` This is correct one should be set in above file. IIS can install ARR module.